# Issues with parallel and transcoding video

Tags: bash, transcoding

Hey guys I'm getting a weird error even though `set -x` isn't showing me anything noticeable. It looks like my `cmds` aren't actually getting processed by parallel, or at least that is the assumption. the script below should do the following

- find all the contents
- push them all through a switch to ensure no rewriting of same formats happen
- re-encode them into html5 video formats (webm ogg and mp4 via h264)
- move those files

Can someone briefly run this code and let me know what is going on? I'm sure its something simple, but it's escaping me atm...

```
#!/bin/bash
# Video transcoder

# CPR : Jd Daniel
# MOD : 2014-02-20 @ 10:51:25
# VER : Beta 1

# proto: cd drop ; types=(asf asx avi flv m4v mov mp4 mpg rm swf vob wmv); for i in "${types[@]}"; do touch "video.${i}"; done;

inp="drop"
out="export"

## test for reqs of exit
for requires in ffmpeg parallel; do
    hash $requires 2>/dev/null || { 
        echo >&2 "I require $requires to run but it's not installed.  Aborting."; exit 1; 
    }
done


## dectypes
declare -r fpath=$( cd "$(dirname "$0")" ; pwd -P )
declare -r types="asf\|asx\|avi\|flv\|m4v\|mov\|mp4\|mpg\|ogg\|rm\|swf\|vob\|webm\|wmv"
declare -r allow=( mp4 ogg webm )
##

    for dir in "$inp" "$out"; do
        [ -d "$fpath/$dir" ] || { mkdir -p "$fpath/$dir"; } # create if not available
    done

        [ -z "$(ls $fpath/$inp)" ] && { "$fpath is empty, finished..."; exit 0; } # exit when empty


    ## start video conversion
    cd $fpath ; for video in $(find . -type f -iregex ".*\(${types}\)" -printf '%P\0 '); do

        skip=0 #reset skip flag 
        name=$(echo $video |awk -NF '.' '{print $1}')
        exts=$(echo $video |awk -NF '.' '{print $2}')

        # assign predetermined pos
        for (( i = 0; i < ${#allow[@]}; i++ )); do
           if [ "${allow[$i]}" = "${exts}" ]; then
               skip=$(($i + 1));
           fi
        done

        cmds=() # empty
        [[ $skip = 1 ]] || { cmds+=("'$video' -b 1500k -vcodec libx264   -vpre   slow      -vpre baseline -g 30          '$name.mp4' ") ; }
        [[ $skip = 2 ]] || { cmds+=("'$video' -b 1500k -vcodec libvpx    -acodec libvorbis -ab   160000   -f webm -g 30  '$name.webm'") ; }
        [[ $skip = 3 ]] || { cmds+=("'$video' -b 1500k -vcodec libtheora -acodec libvorbis -ab   160000   -g 30          '$name.ogg' ") ; }

        echo "${cmds[@]}" | parallel --gnu -j10 ffmpeg -i $fpath/$inp/{/}\;

        for ext in "${allow[@]}"; do
            [ -a "${fpath}/${inp}/${name}.{ext}" ] && mv "${fpath}/${inp}/${name}.{ext}" "${fpath}/${out}/"
        done

    done
```

A link to the repo can be found here [transcoder](https://github.com/ehime/Transcoder.git). Please feel free to use this on YOU OWN PROJECTS!!!! Who knows how it can come in handy, but i'd love to see it shared ;)

Comment: @NevikRehnel sorry about the GIT tag, i think it asked due to me specifying the repo in there =P silly me for not paying attention to my tagging

Comment: Are you sure that you wanted variables like `$video` and `$name.ext` within __single-quotes__?

Comment: Yeah that was a sticky point I saw that I was getting something like `ffmpeg -i /path/to/'drop.mp4'` after removal though I am still getting the missing video shenanigans

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ended up with this, no longer uses parallel but still does background tasks

```
#!/bin/bash
# Video transcoder

# CPR : Jd Daniel :: Ehime-ken
# MOD : 2014-02-24 @ 16:34:29
# VER : Beta 3


inp="drop"
out="export"

clear # set -x

## test for reqs of exit
for requires in ffmpeg parallel; do
    hash $requires 2>/dev/null || {
        echo >&2 "I require $requires to run but it's not installed.  Aborting."; exit 1;
    }
done


## dectypes
declare -r fpath=$( cd "$(dirname "$0")" ; pwd -P )
declare -r types="asf\|asx\|avi\|flv\|m4v\|mkv\|mov\|mp4\|mpg\|ogg\|rm\|swf\|vob\|webm\|wmv"
declare -r allow=( mp4 ogg webm )
##

    for dir in "$inp" "$out"; do
        [ -d "$fpath/$dir" ] || { mkdir -p "$fpath/$dir"; } # create if not available
    done

    [ -z "$(ls $fpath/$inp)" ] && { "$fpath is empty, finished..."; exit 0; } # exit when empty


    ## start video conversion
    cd $fpath ; while IFS= read -r video; do

        skip=0 #reset skip flag
        name="${video%.*}"
        exts="${video##*.}"

        # assign predetermined pos
        for (( i = 0; i < ${#allow[@]}; i++ )); do
           if [ "${allow[$i]}" = "${exts}" ]; then
               skip=$(($i + 1));
           fi
        done


        pids=() # pid track if we want to use it later for something
        [[ $skip = 1 ]] || { ffmpeg -y -i "$inp/$video" -vb 1500k -vcodec libx264 -vpre slow -vpre baseline -g 30 "$out/${name}.mp4" 2> /dev/null & } # \n pid+="$! " # if we're going to do post proc kill work later
        [[ $skip = 2 ]] || { ffmpeg -y -i "$inp/$video" -vb 1500k -vcodec libvpx -acodec libvorbis -ab 160000 -f webm -g 30 "$out/${name}.webm" 2> /dev/null & }
        [[ $skip = 3 ]] || { ffmpeg -y -i "$inp/$video" -vb 1500k -vcodec libtheora -acodec libvorbis -ab 160000 -g 30 "$out/${name}.ogg" 2> /dev/null & }


        # move out of path
        for ext in "${allow[@]}"; do
            [ -a "$inp/$name.$ext" ] && cp -f "$inp/$name.$ext" "$out/" &
        done

        for job in `jobs -p`; do
            echo "Job: $job"
            wait $job || let "FAIL+=1"
        done

        [ "0" == "$FAIL" ] && echo "YAY!" || echo "FAIL! ($FAIL)"

    done <<< $(find "$fpath/$inp" -type f -iregex ".*\(${types}\)" -printf '%P\0 ')
```